# For Firefox, is there a file size limit for webappsstore.sqlite?

Tags: firefox

I've begun creating web apps that use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#localStorage), and since the data stored here persists over multiple browser sessions and pages, I was wondering how long this data lasts for? I only need to store data in there for at most, a month, and definitely I do not want it to be stored indefinitely.

So, does the data eventually clear automatically or will I also have to take into account clearing it myself? Also, I'm guessing there must be some security in place, so that I can't just put localStorage.clear() in my code (I'm currently typing this in Firebug when I need it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about a limit (probably a setting in the browser), but localStorage is forever

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_webstorage.asp

Not 100% sure, but this might be the firefox setting:

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Dom.storage.default_quota

As for security, according to the article you linked that should be by domain (i.e. not being allowed to touch higher level domains in FF3+ ).

Comment: Okay, so it looks like it's about 5 MB (by default) per site, which is still quite a lot, although I guess I'll make do rather than tweak that setting. Also, yeah it looks like these settings are on a per-domain basis so that's good. I wonder how safe globalStorage is, though, in that case.

Comment: As safe as your defense against XSS probably.